# possible to add to Django ManyToManyField with only instance IDs

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

Is it possible to add to a ManyToManyField when you've only the list of IDs, without a db hit to retrieve instances (add_instances_but_with_db_hit does this, but with a hit).

Thanks.

```
class WorkerCombinedPayment(AbstractReimbursement):
    charge_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)

class MassPayment(TimeStampedModel):
    list_payments = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    paypal_batch_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    success = models.NullBooleanField()
    response_from_paypal = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    workercombinedpayments = models.ManyToManyField(WorkerCombinedPayment)

    def add_instances_but_with_db_hit(self, id_list):
        found = WorkerCombinedPayment.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
        self.workercombinedpayments.add(found)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can just pass the IDs:

```
self.workercombinedpayments.add(*id_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The facebook Django Python Web Framework group answered my question in this [thread](https://www.facebook.com/groups/python.django/permalink/1775705155814056/?comment_id=1775715895812982&notif_id=1522226642870596&notif_t=group_comment&ref=notif). Here are the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) on 'set'. Nb this will replace existing contents. See @DanielRoseman's accepted answer if you want to update your field, not overwrite it.

```
class WorkerCombinedPayment(AbstractReimbursement):
    charge_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)

class MassPayment(TimeStampedModel):
    list_payments = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    paypal_batch_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    success = models.NullBooleanField()
    response_from_paypal = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    workercombinedpayments = models.ManyToManyField(WorkerCombinedPayment)

    def add_instances(self, id_list):
        self.workercombinedpayments.set(id_list)
```